# Windows 7 Mobile Broadband API - Crash with no exception

Tags: c#, windows-7, com, mobile-broadband-api

The following code exits before it finishes with no exception:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MbnConnectionManager connectionManager = new MbnConnectionManager();
        IMbnConnectionManager connectionManagerInterface = (IMbnConnectionManager)connectionManager;
       IMbnConnection[] connections = (IMbnConnection[])connectionManagerInterface.GetConnections();


       (IMbnConnectionProfileManager)connectionProfile;
        MbnApi.MbnInterfaceManager interfaceManager = new MbnInterfaceManager();
        MbnApi.IMbnInterfaceManager interfaceManagerInterface = (IMbnInterfaceManager)interfaceManager;

        IMbnInterface[] interfaces = interfaceManagerInterface.GetInterfaces() as IMbnInterface[];

        foreach (IMbnInterface mbnInterface in interfaces)
        {
            MBN_PROVIDER homeProvider = mbnInterface.GetHomeProvider(out homeProvider);
        }

    }
```

This line seems to be causing the crash -

```
MBN_PROVIDER homeProvider = mbnInterface.GetHomeProvider(out homeProvider);
```

Why would this occur and is there any way to see what is really happening inside the Mobile Broadband API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you registered a broadband device in your system?

1. Open your network and sharing center and see if there is a Mobile Broadband Connection device.
2. Try to run the following command: `netsh mbn show interfaces`

Comment: I no longer have access to the device I was testing this with, but I will check if any other devices I have use this API. For anyone else searching for information on this it seems like Huawei devices *do not* use this API. Thanks for your answer - good to have extra info at any rate.

Comment: netsh>mbn show interfaces
There is no Mobile Broadband interface

Comment: It depends on the device driver whether the device uses MBN API.  This is specified by the device provider (telecom company), who gets a customised driver, not the manufacturer.